# I need help with this question about convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{∞} a_n$ be a convergent series, consider a growing sequence where $n_1<n_2<...$ , and define

• $b_1=a_1+...+a_{n_1}$;
• $b_2=a_{n_1+1}+...+a_{n_2}$;
• $b_3=a_{n_2+1}+...+a_{n_3}$, and so on.

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{∞}b_n=\sum_{n=1}^{∞}a_n$

So, I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{∞} a_n=a_1+a_2+a_3+...$

And I know that
$\sum_{n=1}^{∞}b_n=b_1+b_2+b_3+...=a_1+...+a_{n_1}+a_{n_1+1}+...+a_{n_2}+a_{n_2+1}+...+a_{n_3}+...$

But how can I prove they are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Let the series converge to $L$. Therefore
$$
{\exists M\ \ \ ,\ \ \ n>M\implies|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i-L|<\epsilon_1}.
$$
All you need to prove, is that
$$
\exists N\ \ \ , \ \ \ m,n>N\implies |\sum_{i=1}^m a_i-\sum_{i=1}^n b_i|<\epsilon_2,
$$
by expressing $b_n$ in terms of $a_n$ in a bounded series. Can you finish now?